# ls /dev/sda2 - same as dir c:

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint, ls

I want to install linux mint. The problem is, I have drive c and d.
I want to install it in drive c.

I think it is /dev/sda2 but I`m not sure. I want to dir this drive to see files and check if I can format it or not.

I tried `ls /dev/sda2` but it prints `/dev/sda2` I want to see the files. How can I do this

Comment: did you run this ls command at the live boot?

Comment: yes, in live dvd! @Rudolph

Comment: ls /dev/sda2 shows you the device /dev/sda2. You want the contents, for that first `mount` it.

Comment: check this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132767